# Remove a string that can have many deviation in PHP

Tags: php, string

I have a large string and I need to remove something like this from it:

```
<post user='test' id='test'></post>
```

`test` can be any value. I known that you can do this with `regex`. But I need this to be a standard PHP execution, as my server cannot support `regex` due to the amount of users.

Anyone got any ideas; any help would be appreciated.

Comment: And what should be removed?

Comment: @u_mulder I have a extra large string with a few randomly placed "<post user='///' id='///'></post>" inside the string (/// = any possible value) and I would like to have the <post></post> tag removed from it, do you have any idea how???

Comment: Use `preg_replace("~<post\s+user='[^']*'\s+id='[^']*'></post>~", "", $s)`

Comment: Are you sure you can't use regexp? It's pretty efficient except in certain pathological cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `strpos` and `substr` like this:

```
while(($startPos = strpos($html, '<post')) !== FALSE && ($endPos = strpos($html, '</post>', $startPos)) !== FALSE){
    $html = substr($html, 0, $startPos) . substr($html, $endPos + strlen('</post>'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function.

```
explode("'", $string);
```

Comment: How does that help with removing an HTML tag? Did you misunderstand the question?